# How to backup my hosted SVN repository?

Tags: svn, assembla

I am using a cloud SVN service ([asssembla](http://www.assembla.com/))  to manage my personal project source files.

I am looking for a way to automatically backup my project files.

Seems like I can export a dump with the service REST api,  but I want the uncompressed files.

Is there some product that will connect in a pre-scheduled times to the SVN server, download the latest files and copy them to some folder?

Comment: cron + `svn export` or just `svn co`

Comment: I'm with nos. I would just go on some server somewhere and check out the code. When I want to refresh my backup, I log on my backup server and do `svn update`, or automated with a cron job.

Comment: @sylvanaar - I am looking for automatic tool. the question in your link is providing the way to do it by yourself.

Comment: @Tibo did you read: http://www.assembla.com/features/subversion?locale=en#6 or "Schedule automatic backups to your own private Amazon S3 storage account."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of Subversion 1.4, there's a tool called [svnsync](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.4/svn.ref.svnsync.html) to mirror one complete repository into another. That way, you may keep a local backup:

```
svnsync init file:⁄⁄⁄backup/directory svn://svn.example.com/remote/repo
svnsync sync svn://svn.example.com/remote/repo
```

As an alternative, you could switch to a [Distributed VCS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_revision_control) like GIT or Bazaar, where all members of a repository keep their local copy.

Answer (score 0):

It is not too much hard. You can write your own script to get the entire code and copy that somewhere. Then use an operating system service (e.g. Windows Task Scheduler) to run it periodically.